# Automatic conversion of hh:mm:ss:fff to hh:mm:ss,fff format in Excel for large data sets

Tags: excel, data-analysis

I want to convert a time stamp from hh:mm:ss:fff to hh:mm:ss,fff format in Excel. Is there some method to do that automatically, since i have a large number of time stamps(circa 800) and manual editing will take a long time.

Comment: What have you tried?  You can format a whole column, or even a worksheet, at once; why are you having problems formatting a group of cells?

Comment: I have tried formating the column to the specific hh:mm:ss,fff format. Thought it changes to that format but i still have to manually change the data inside to cells from hh:mm:ss:fff to hh:mm:ss,fff by one by one conversion of : to ,

Comment: In your locale, is the decimal point represented by the comma?

Comment: yes, since i am working with this data in Germany and here the regional settings are set by default to comma.

Comment: OK, I have posted a possible solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Format an adjacent column with your desired format.

Then, in that column, enter a formula like:

```
=--SUBSTITUTE(A1;":";",";3)
```

where `A1` is in the column with your data

I hope I have the separators correct.  In my US English version the formula would be:

```
=--SUBSTITUTE(A1,":",".",3)
```

Fill down the column as far as necessary.

Then use `Copy/Paste Special` for Values and, if necessary, format, to remove the formula.

Comment: You are most welcome.  Please remember to mark my response as the answer, by selecting the check mark at the upper left of the response.

Comment: I see that Substitute is behaving differently if preceded by the 2 hyphens or not. What's the difference please? Supposing to want hh:mm:ss and get rid of the :fff ?

Comment: @TormyVanCool The double unary is one of many ways to change text that looks like a numeric value into a numeric value. Your second question lacks detail and is better posed as a separate question with full detail as to exactly what you want to do, what you have tried and where you have run into a problem.